Best UX Practice for Closing a Multi-Selection Popup
In our latest design iteration, we have a popup that allows users to make multiple selections, which directly update the datagrid behind it. Since multiple selections are required, the popup cannot close after selecting a single item.
Currently, the popup can be closed by clicking outside of it, but there's no clear visual indication that this is an option. I’m unsure whether I should add a dedicated close button. Here’s why I’m conflicted:
A "Cancel" button feels inappropriate since selections are actively made and reflected in the datagrid, not undone.
An "Apply" button doesn’t make sense either, as the changes are immediately applied to the datagrid.
Does anyone have recommendations for the best way to design this interaction? Should I include a close button or use another approach to make closing the popup more intuitive?

There are many options that do not require the use of Close, OK, Cancel, Accept or any buttons except those that are specific to the settings. Graphical applications such as Figma or Apple Numbers have WISYWIG configuration options for items within the document that do not require a confirmation button:

Side panel of options
Draggable floating window
Minimizable floating window


It largely depends on what the dialog is doing, but generally leave as many exit vectors for a modal dialog as possible. Different users will have different interaction habits, so there's no reason to cut off the natural flow for each one.

Adding an X button at the corner will reinforce the concept of popup to the user
If the changes are automatically applied, a simple Close or Ok is helpful.

But also ask yourself: does it really need to be a modal? perhaps it could be a sidebar as Danielilo suggests.

Apart from the debates over whether it should be a popup or not, the close button functionality expresses the intention in a visually appealing way.
It’s either with a button with ‘close’ text or an ‘x’ in it. It’s not matter of this question as it can be choice of your preference.
Secondly, I’d recommend displaying a text that informs the user about the stage of the saving process where the interaction happens exactly.
In this specific case, ‘Auto saving/saved’ or ‘Changes are (being) applied’ texts instead of any button to be placed exactly where the buttons should be displayed makes more sense.
